# How to query documents of one model, from referenced field from another model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How I could query with mongoose all food by City _id which is referenced in Place model, and Place model referenced in Food model.
EDIT: (example) If I select New York (City), I want to get all food from New York.

```
const FoodSchema = new Schema({
  place: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Place',
    required: true
}})


const PlaceSchema = new Schema({
  city: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'City',
    required: true
}})
const CitySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String}})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `populate()` multiple times. This code from the official documentation gives an example where they query a user, populates its friends, and then the friends of the friends:

```
User.
  findOne({ name: 'Val' }).
  populate({
    path: 'friends',
    // Get friends of friends - populate the 'friends' array for every friend
    populate: { path: 'friends' }
  });
```

In your case this would be

```
Food.find().populate({path: 'place', populate: {path: 'city'}})
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood me. I have to choose a city which is referenced in place (restauraunt) and to filter all food from places from that city